# onclick not working with dynamically-added buttons

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension

#### Problem

Adding an event handler for click events with dynamically added buttons does not result in anything when clicked. I'm trying to build a build a chrome extension that dynamically adds a button.

#### Code

- In content script (js)

```
// 1. Create the button
        var button = document.createElement("button");
        button.innerHTML = "Do Something";

        // 2. Append somewhere in the document body
        var body = document.getElementsByTagName("body")[0];
        body.appendChild(button);

        // 3. Add event handler
        button.addEventListener ("click", function() {
          alert("did something");
        });
```

- While the button does get rendered, clicking the button does nothing.

#### Notes

- Event handlers for checkboxes work, though!  Uses `href = "javascript: function()"`

  ```
  var check = document.createElement("input");
        check.id = "checkbox1";
        check.type = "checkbox";

          //if check is checked, then call removeSticky()
        check.href="javascript:removeSticky()"
        check.addEventListener('change', () => {
              if (check.checked) {
                  removeSticky();
              } else {
                  // nothing
              }
        });

        document.getElementById("sticky").append(check);


  //hidesthe sticky note
  function removeSticky() {
    window.alert("removeSticky() is working.");
    // Removes an element from the document.
    var element = document.getElementById("sticky");
    element.style.display = "none";
  }
  ```
- However, doing the same with the BUTTON causes `removeSticky()` to be called whenever the webpage is fully loaded, when the user hasn't clicked anything yet.

Comment: The first code is correct and it should work. The fact that it doesn't can mean something is interfering, for example maybe the page has a global click handler that stops propagation of the event. In that case you can try specifying `true` in the **third** parameter of addEventListener.

Comment: Try to add event handler before appending the button, although from what you post it should work.